# SQL Server SQL - From and To Min and Max to remove overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to implement SCD type two using the below data set. As you can see there is a multiple records with the same class (highlighted in red) and I wish to combine these two to remove one. basically if such occurs, i wish to take min and max for `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` for the same class.

Can this be acheivable in SQL ? I am using SQL Server 2014 so lead or lag function could be used for this i gues..  but what if there is more than 2 consecutive records with the same class.

And lastly, I want to set the last record's valid to to NULL.

Any help would be appreciated !

[image]

Comment: what indicate the order here?

Comment: SCD type two? What is that exactly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

Comment: I guess ValidFrom indicates the order. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: You guess? What about `class`? my guess is `ORDER BY ValidForm, class` but the point is you need to know what is the order to solve this question, both for join consecutive class rows and assign `NULL` to last row

Comment: and btw, post data as text, we cant copy / paste from image to make a sample.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The order is just validFrom. As you can Class is history attribute of type 2 dimension. The current record for this product is the last record (row number 14)

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data has holes but no overlaps.  If this is generally the case, then this is not too hard:

```
select productid, class, min(validfrom) as validfrom,
       lead(min(validfrom)) over (partition by productid order by min(validfrom)) as validto
from (select scd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by productid, class order by validfrom) as seqnum_pc,
             row_number() over (partition by productid order by validfrom) as seqnum_c
      from scd
     ) s
group by productid, class, (seqnum_c - seqnum_pc);
```

Understanding how this works requires "getting" how the difference in row numbers identifies the group of adjacent class values.  My advice is to run the subquery (perhaps on a subset of your data) to see how the difference works.

Comment: great ! yes it doesn't have any overlaps so this works ! thanks ! But any chance we can get the valid to instead of valid from using the lead function ?

Comment: @superted . . . I'm not sure what your comment refers to. `validto` is calculated using `lead()`.